# react-native-call-receiver error react_native_call_receiver does not exist

Tags: npm, react-native

I am a starter on react native and wanted to use [react-native-call-receiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-receiver) module for learning how to handle call receiving events

I have followed that npm page, and found that in the "register module" section, the author has instructed to add an import statement and new ReactNativeCallReceiver()

However, the template(as shown below)

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication  {

  @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      ......
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          ......
```

within which the code has to be injected is available only in **MainApplication.java** and not under **MainActivity.java** in the path **android/app/src/main/java/[your-app-namespace]/**

(I guess this must be because of the outdated version of manual compared to react. I am using react native 0.41 and react-native-cli 2.0.1)

So i proceeded with the "import" and the "new" statement inside the class, and ran the application, and i get the following error

```
c:\Myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\test_nativebase\MainApplication.java:13: error: package ru.getintime.
react_native_call_receiver does not exist
import ru.getintime.react_native_call_receiver.ReactNativeCallReceiver;
                                              ^
C:\Myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\test_nativebase\MainApplication.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
          new ReactNativeCallReceiver()
              ^
  symbol: class ReactNativeCallReceiver
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

## C:\Myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\test_nativebase\MainActivity.java

```
package com.test_nativebase;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Test_NativeBase";
    }
}
```

## C:\Myapp\android\app\src\main\java\com\test_nativebase\MainApplication.java

```
package com.test_nativebase;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import ru.getintime.react_native_call_receiver.ReactNativeCallReceiver;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new ReactNativeCallReceiver()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

This is what i did:

1. Double Checked whether the import statement is available
2. Double Checked whether the module is installed and saved under node_modules

I checked out github link to file an issue, but the **link that is given on npm is broken**. Can somebody help me sort out this error please ?

Comment: That library is not available in github thats why its showing error.https://github.com/Jenya26/react-native-call-receiver

Comment: @NiteshMishra are you saying that the react-native build process tries to compile the referenced library by fetching it from the Internet even after i installed it locally with "yarn add --library-name--" ? If yes, why and how can i overcome this ?

Comment: @Kdroid so did you get it working ?